# If $|A|=a$, $|B|=b$ and $|C|=c$, what is $|A \cup A \times B \cup A\times B\times C|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $|A|=a$, $|B|=b$ and $|C|=c$, what is the value of $|A \cup A \times B \cup A\times B\times C|$?

My reasoning was that there are two possibilities, either the cartesian product binds stronger, or the union does. But in the latter case it doesn't seem to be well defined, as we don't know what's in A and B (it could be just 4 if A is a subset of B or 7 if they're completely different).

In the first scenario, taking into account that $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|$ I arrive at a set of, $$a ~\text{elements}+a \cdot b ~\text{ordered pairs}+a \cdot b \cdot c ~\text{ordered tuples},$$
or in total $$a+a \cdot b+a \cdot b \cdot c,$$

Elements in the set, which, as I am told by the computer, is incorrect. (In the task there are concrete numbers, so it's not about the formatting.) Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer is right I believe.

Comment: To be clear... when you write $A\cup A\times B\cup A\times B\times C$... do you mean $(A)\cup (A\times B)\cup (A\times B\times C)$ or do you mean $(A\cup A)\times (B\cup A)\times (B\times C)$ or some other way of arranging the parentheses?  There is no "order of operations" that is standard for sets, so your expression is ambiguous.

Comment: @JMoravitz That is not clear in the task, so I suppose it's gotta be your first option, as $A \cup B$ could be anything from 4 to 7.

Comment: @user658409 In the specific task, A=3 ,B=4, C=5, and I got 3+12+60=75.

Comment: Under the most common interpretations then, I agree with an answer of $a+ab+abc$ as it is common to treat singletons as distinct from ordered pairs and further being distinct from ordered triples so when having arrived at taking the union we should be able to assume that there is no overlap between the sets and break it apart with addition.  Depending on how you formally define ordered tuples however, there is technically some chance for some overlap, the ordered tuple $(x,x)$ being indistinguishable from the ordered singleton $(\{x\})$ for instance under Kuratowski's definitions.

Comment: All of the sets are disjoint so the cardinality of their union is the sum of all of their cardinalities. So yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: @AmitTPB Post it as an answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the sets are disjoint so the cardinality of their union is the sum of all of their cardinalities. So yes, your answer is correct.